# Model matrix with n-wise interactions between all variables

Tags: r, model.matrix

I am using the following code to create n-order interactions between variables in a data set. For the case of second-order interactions, I use:

```
train_X <- model.matrix(~.^2, train_data %>% select(-target))
```

That worked properly, nevertheless, when I try to make the n-order term modular to embed this code within a function in the following way, it does not work:

```
n <- 2
train_X <- model.matrix(~.^n, train_data %>% select(-target))
```

Particularly, it returns the following error:

> Error in terms.formula(object, data = data) : invalid power in formula

I have also tried to specify `n = 2L`, but it returns the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try building your formula as a string (using `paste()`, `glue::glue()`, `sprintf()`, or whatever your like) and converting to a formula (using `as.formula()` or `reformulate()`).

```r
train_X <- model.matrix(
   as.formula(sprintf("~.^%d", n)), 
   train_data %>% select(-target))
```

Comment: It worked! Although it crashes if n = 1, so I have to embed the particular case of n = 1 within an if statement

Comment: OK, I see: "invalid power in formula"